# Fetching the json array data using query

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am try to fetch the array from JSON.
Json would look

```
`["11545934":{
    "link":"www.stackoverflow.com",
    "title":"Stackoverflow",
    "desc":"Que les choses soient claires : j'adore &ecirc;tre m&egrave;re",
    "video":[
        {
            "vdb_574dafbee4b0a060467cc0ad564e003d67b62214082cc703":"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\",57334982e4b0fa8a6cebbb47,5732062ee4b000828332b12e,571fd8c8e4b0576eca3601b0,57193626e4b0314d67a6baf1,570d0c30e4b0d05a3a27e825,570822e9e4b02a40f6485480,56e82eb5e4b01fe390d92a3f/blabla.js\"></script>"
        }
    ]
},"11603404":{
    "link":"http://stackoverflow.com",
    "title":"Title goes here",
    "desc":"j'ai tenu bon. Il a suffi de quelques jours pour commencer.",
    "video":[
        {
            "vdb_574dafbee4b0a060467cc0ad564e003d67b62214082cc703":"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"5735be05e4b0550e88349a78,573f2183e4b0dd279012295d,572c6ff1e4b07894140ab60c,560ece45e4b06f5b8c4227dc/blabla.js\"></script>"
        }
    ]
},
"11605608":{
    "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/",
    "title":"The tittle goes here",
    "desc":"tordue pour vendre le projet &agrave; l'opinion publique.",
    "video":[
        {
            "vdb_574dafbee4b0a060467cc0ad564e003d67b62214082cc703":"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\",5533ba45e4b0280be0f190af/blabla.js\"></script>"
        }
    ]
},`
```

i am parsing the json to get the video contents here.

My jquery goes like this

```
        $.ajax({
        url: "data.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(obj) {
            $.each(obj, function(key,val){
                val.link; /*i get the link*/
                $.each(val.video, function(i, j){
                    alert(j);/*tried*/
                    alert(this[j]) /*tried*/

                })
            });

        }
    });
```

this code is not generating the output i want, where am i going wrong here.

Comment: This is not valid JSON to begin with.

Comment: This is the feed i am getting. can't change it. i will have to play with it...

Comment: Couldn't find any solution.  Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "data.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(obj) {
        $.each(obj, function(key,val){
            val.link; /*i get the link*/
            $.each(val.video, function(i, j){
                alert(j);/*tried*/
                $.each(j, function(x,y)){
                   alert(y)
                }
            })
        });

    }
});
```

the array is a multidimensional array so i had to loop through again to get the value and key.